# Is there a way of making a folder icon available from any pc (windows)?

Tags: windows, windows-10, icons

I have a lot of documents and folders, and using custom folder icons is a good way to keep organized and accessible folders. The thing is I usually make back-ups of such folders to another computer and then the icons doesn't show (the problem being the original folder in one pc is in D drive and the destination folder being in a C drive).

So I'm looking for a way to link an icon to a folder that doesn't depend on the location of it.

Comment: If you copy the icon you want into the folder itself (you can name it `folder.ico`) then you can use the folder **Properties** -> **Customise** to select it as the folder icon. Because it's in the folder itself, you can do this on any PC which is accessing it.

Comment: @AFH but it will still look for the icon on the folder location, but that location changes from one PC to another. I already have the icon stored in the folder, but in one PC the folder will be in C:/folder and in the other, in D:/folder, for example

Comment: No, it will look in the location where you told that PC to find it.

Comment: @AFH but I would have to tell each PC where to find the icon for every folder, wouldn't I? Because if I copy a folder from one PC's C:/folder to another one's C:/folder it shows the icon, but it doesn't if I move it to another location. At least that's what happened to me.

Comment: I implied that in my first comment. Wherever the icon is, you will need to tell the local Windows to use it. By putting it in the folder itself, you make sure it's available on whichever PC it is backed up on.

Comment: @AFH Oh, ok. That would be ok if I have to change 1 or 2 folder icons, but it's not so easy when you have lots of folders (that being the reason of using custom icons). So what I was looking for was if there was a method to automatically associate a folder with an icon, so it would show the icon in any PC without having to change the icon manually for each folder.

Comment: I'm very hazy about it, but I seem to remember that years ago, you could put `folder.ico` in a folder, and Windows would use it as the folder icon, but it doesn't happen now, and I can't remember how long ago or which variety of Windows. I suppose there could now be a registry setting to allow it, but I've no idea where it would be.